# Mnemonic or Glyph Origin for 御

Tags: characters, character-identification, glyph-origin

I can't fiugure out suitable mnemonic for 御.

Does someone has a good idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「御」 originally meant *to operate* or *manage/control*, then extended to mean the adjective *imperial*.

> The meaning *to drive a carriage* is specifically held by the character 「馭」; when 「御」 is used for this meaning, it is a [rebus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus#Rebus_principle) of 「馭」.

---

<kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image]
[菁](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)1.1
[合集6057](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=6057&jgwfl=)</kbd>
<kbd>[隸定](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E9%9A%B6%E5%AE%9A)
[image]</kbd>

「御」 (*to operate/manage*) originally depicted a [*kneeling person* 「卩」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=21830) using (*operating*) a [*pestle* 「午」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=103).

> *Pestle* is now written as the derivative character 「杵」.

Later on, two verb-like markers were added:

- 「彳」 (half of the character [「行」, *picture of a road intersection*](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=447) > *roads, travelling*)

  <kbd>商
  甲
  [image]
  [前](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)2.18.6
  [合集8189](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=8189&jgwfl=)</kbd>
  <kbd>隸定
  [image]</kbd>
- [「止」 (*picture of a foot*](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=141) > *walking*). This leads on to the modern form 「御」.

  <kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
  [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
  [image]
  頌鼎
  [集成2829](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2829&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
  [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
  [image]
  [秦](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)115
  [睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)</kbd><kbd>今
  [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
  [image]</kbd>

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)

Answer (score 4):

**Stop driving carriage at noon.**

[image]

I'm boring...

Hope you can figure it out....

Explanation really hurts,my English very bad,now I feel my brain'RAM overflowed.

御 originally means 'driving a carriage'. This carriage need two people to fire up just like the one in the  picture .

It can be broken down into several parts：彳，卸。
If you  think 卸 is still too complex,then break it down to  午，止，卩。

彳：There are a lot of character involve it,this component means 'two people' or '行'.
卩： imagine a  nodding horse.

I can't continue to explain, I see that "blue screen". Sorry.

Comment: A little explanation couldn't hurt

Comment: +1 for the drawing. lol